# Calling a method with Provider.of(context) inside of dispose() method cause "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When I tried to call a method inside of State dispose method like below.

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false).close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I got this.

```
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3508
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3522
#2      Element.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3588
#3      Provider.of 
package:provider/src/provider.dart:219
#4      _MySecondPageState.dispose 
package:test_space/main.dart:138
...
```

This is my example AppProvider

```
class AppProvider {
  close() {}
}
```

and I wrapped MaterialApp with AppProvider

```
return Provider<AppProvider>(
      create: (_) => AppProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomeScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
```

I'm not sure how to do this `To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.`
I'm currently using `provider: ^4.0.2`.

I used to do it the same, **using Provider.of(context) inside of dispose()**, without this exception before. Is this because new flutter version?
Also, I realized there is the deactivate() method, should I use deactivate() method instead of dispose() method?

**[UPDATED]**

```
  AppProvider _appProvider;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _appProvider.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

[I could also use deactivate in a certain case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56387430/12208004)

```
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .close();
    super.deactivate();
  }
```

Comment: Check out the accepted answer below--
It works for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64983187/12079909

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you are trying to close something which is defined in your AppProvider class. If AppProvider class is extending ChangeNotifier, the change notifier class provides dispose method, you can override it and then call the close function inside the AppProvider class only.

Comment: I didn't extend ChangeNotifier. I'm not sure, but when try to use `context` inside of `dispose()`, it throw an exception.

Comment: same issue, that works for me.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember this behaviour is long ago, I usually use [`after_layout`](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout) to solve it like:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with AfterLayoutMixin {
  AppProvider _appProvider;

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    _appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _appProvider.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to dispose something before leaving context, you can dispose it in `willPopScope`

```
 WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () {
       context.read<AppProvider().myController?.dispose();
       Navigator.pop(context);
       return Future.value(false);
    },
    child: ...,
 )
```

Comment: It is not a reliable solution as ```onWillPop``` doesnt gets called with Navigator.pushReplacement() or with bottom navigation bars.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it disables other navigation like tap out side modal or back button for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `Provider.dispose` callback, which is called right when the provider is unmounted from the widget tree:

```
return Provider<AppProvider>(
      create: (_) => AppProvider(),
      dispose: (_, appProvider) => appProvider.close()
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomeScreen(),
        },
      ),
```