# Riverpod: Set state of StateNotifierProvider in dispose method

Tags: riverpod

I have the following Riverpod StateNotifierProvider:

```
class DisconnectString extends StateNotifier<String> {
  DisconnectString() : super('default string value');

  void change(String text) => state = text;
}

final disconnectString = StateNotifierProvider<DisconnectString, String>(
    (ref) => DisconnectString());
```

Depending on the current screen, the disconnect string should be different. Currently I'm able to change the string when entering a new screen in the initState method:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      ref.read(disconnectString.notifier).change('A new string value');
    });
  }
```

However, I'm not able to set it back to the default value in the dispose method.

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    ref.read(disconnectString.notifier).change('default string value');
  }
```

I just get "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe"

I could not find any stackOverflow Riverpod issues regarding this. However, I tried all the solutions in this ticket [Calling a method with Provider.of(context) inside of dispose() method cause "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60038200/calling-a-method-with-provider-ofcontext-inside-of-dispose-method-cause-loo), without success.

For example I tried to store the Reader (ref.read) in a variable and use that in the dispose method, but it didn't work.

Comment: `Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {ref.read(disconnectString.notifier).change('default string value');});` in dispose also not work?

Comment: No, that does not work. I still get "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe" If i wrap it in a zero duration future delay.

Comment: Can you provide a minimally reproducible copy-run example?